# Search Engine using TextBox, ComboBox and RadioButton

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, search, search-engine

I am developing a search engine within WindowsForms,
I'm using VB.Net 2010 and SQL Server 2008,
My connection is ADO.Net

I experience difficulties in concatenating strings whenever I retrieve records from the database using a textbox, combobox and a radiobutton.

I would like to retrieve record based from the values of those objects,

```
Dim Condition1 As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim Condition2 As String = ComboBox1.Text
Dim Condition3  As String = RadioButton.Text
```

When I try to concatenate, I use the operator AND..

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (Condition1 AND Condition2 AND Conditon3)
```

It gives me an error when some objects doesnt have a value.

```
Incorrect syntax near the word AND.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER concatenate strings to make queries! use [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)! The query you posted is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
Dim query as String = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Column1 = @Column1 AND 
                             Column2 = @Column2 AND Column3 = @Column3"
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", textBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", comboBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column3", radioButton1.Text)
```

Apart from the above, the conditions you are trying to concatenate are not valid. Anything that comes after the `WHERE` clause should specify the column name and the value like what I did above. So condition1 should be for example :

```
// If the column type is varchar then single quotes must be used
Dim Condition1 As String = String.Format("Name = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: @TheOxblood please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you think it was helpful.

Comment: You did'nt answer my question, how I may able to filter records based from multiple conditions?

Comment: Can I ask some questions? What if one of those objects doesn't have a value? It would look like..

SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Column1 = '' AND Column2 = @Column2 AND Column3 = @Column3"

the statements would encounter an error, incorrect syntax near Column1